# Python 3x Function runs without being called

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

here is My code

```
code
__author__ = 'Jared Reabow'
__name__ = 'Assignment 2 Dice game'
#Date created: 14/11/2014
#Date modified 17/11/2014
#Purpose: A game to get the highest score by rolling 5 virtual dice.

import random 


#pre defined variables
NumberOfDice = 5 #this variable defined how many dice are to be rolled



def rollDice(NumberOfDice):
        dice = [] #this is the creation of an unlimited array (list), it containes the values of the 5 rolled dice.
        RunCount1 = 1 #This defines the number of times the first while loop has run
        while RunCount1 <= NumberOfDice:
                #print("this loop has run " , RunCount1 , " cycles.") #this is some debugging to make sure how many time the loop has run
                TempArrayHolder = random.randint(1,6) #This holds the random digit one at a time for each of the dice in the dice Array.
                dice.append(TempArrayHolder) #this takes the TempArrayHolder value and feeds it into the array called dice.
                RunCount1 += 1 #this counts up each time the while loop is run.
        return dice

rollDice(NumberOfDice)
dice = rollDice(NumberOfDice)
print(dice,"debug") #Debug to output dice array in order to confirm it is functioning

def countVals(dice,NumberOfDice):
    totals = [0]*6 #this is the creation of a array(list) to count the number of times, number 1-6 are rolled
    #print(dice, "debug CountVals function")
    SubRunCount = 0
    while SubRunCount < NumberOfDice:
         totals[dice[SubRunCount -1] -1] += 1 #this is the key line for totals, it takes the dice value -1(to d eal with starting at 0) and uses it
         #to define the array position in totals where 1 is then added.
         #print(totals)
         SubRunCount += 1
    return totals

countVals(dice,NumberOfDice)
totals = countVals(dice,NumberOfDice)
print("totals = ",totals)
```

The indentation may be a bit wrong, I am new to stackoverflow.
My issue as stated in the title is that both functions will run regardless of being called or not, but they will run twice if called.

I read somewhere that removing the brackets from:

```
dice = rollDice(NumberOfDice)
```

so that it is this

```
dice = rollDice
```

would fix the issue, and to some extent it does something but not what I want.
if I do the above,it outputs

```
<function rollDice at 0x00000000022ACBF8> debug
```

rather than running the function, so I am left very stuck.

I would appreciate detailed explanation as to what is happening?

Update: I had called the function twice by mistake.
I thought I needed to run it before i could use its returned output, but no it will when whenever used in the code.

Comment: Where did you read that? The first version calls `rollDice` with a single argument, `NumberOfDice`, and assigns the result of that call (`return` value) to the name `dice`; the second just *assigns the function itself* to the name `dice`.

Answer (score 0):

You do call `rollDice()` twice:

```
rollDice(NumberOfDice)
dice = rollDice(NumberOfDice)
```

The first time you ignore the return value, so you can just remove that call.

You do the same with `countVals`:

```
countVals(dice,NumberOfDice)
totals = countVals(dice,NumberOfDice)
```

Again, that's *two* calls, not one, and the first one ignores the return value; just remove those lines altogether.

Comment: so what you are saying is rather than
countVals(dice,NumberOfDice)
totals = countVals(dice,NumberOfDice
I should put
totals = countVals(dice,NumberOfDice

Comment: @JaredReabow: Exactly. Otherwise you are calling the function and ignoring the result, then calling the function and storing the result. That's just extra work your code doesn't need to do.